# Шифрование файла в ресурсах

Tags: c#

Подскажите есть ли какие-нибудь методы шифрования позволяющие зашифровать исходный код (`txt,exe`) файла в ресурсах?

Comment: Любой метод шифрования сделанный на c# будет достаточно просто "взламать". Кроме случаев когда ключ шифрования будет находится не в exe-файле, а браться извне

Comment: Логику придумаю, я просто хочу понять можно ли зашифровать прямо из ресурсов файл ( или же его нужно сначала куда-то скопировать, шифрануть и после обратно - заменить файл ресурса на новый зашифрованный)

Comment: Скорее всего вам так и придется делать. Вряд ли этот функционал встроен в саму систему ресурсов

Comment: @Zergatul, Хмм, ладно) И расшифровку тоже видимо нельзя проводить прямо из ресурсов? :( Плохо что придётся извлекать содержимое на локальный диск.

Comment: Почему на диск? Вы можете сделать все в памяти

Comment: @Zergatul, Никогда не работал, можно подробнее?

Comment: Стандартные классы для работы с ресурсами на выходе дают или массив байт, или стрим. Вы работаете с ним в памяти. Я не помню, как они называются, можете поискать, там все просто.